# How to hide and fade div using jQuery and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have HTML in which I want to make some divs show one above another in the Z axis, with "world" being hidden, and div with id "hello" fade out, and div with id "world" fade in thereafter?

I am using jQuery and CSS:

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="hello">test</div>
  <div id="world">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `hide`, `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` considering your `jquery` is `ready`

```js
$('#world').hide();
$('#hello').fadeOut(function() {
  $('#world').fadeIn(function() {
     //do your stuff
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="hello">hello</div>
  <div id="world">world</div>
</div>
```

You can even hide the world div initially with css using `display: none` property, since `$('#world').hide()` does the exact same thing.

You can change the duration of fading effect by providing duration parameter:

```js
var duration = 2000; //in milliseconds

$('#hello').fadeOut(duration, function() {
  $('#world').fadeIn(duration, function() {
    //do your stuff
  });
});
```

```css
#world {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="hello">hello</div>
  <div id="world">world</div>
</div>
```

Read more about `fading` Here:
https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/

Comment: Adding some delay in fadeOut and fadeIn will make the fade effect more noticeable, see, http://jsbin.com/hasusubowe/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery .hide() with fading:

```
$("div_name").click(function () {
      $(this).hide("fade", {}, 1000);
});
```

To fade out:

```
$( "#div_id" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

To fade in:

```
$( "#div_id" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cab sinply use the jQuery .**hide** , .**fadeIn** and .**fadeOut** events:

for .hide(), use

```
$('#id').hide("fade",{
//do your stuffs
},time-duration);
```

for fadeOut:

```
$("#id").fadeOut("duration");
```

for fadeIn:

```
$("#id").fadeIn("duration");
```

and use them respectively with your divs or on their clicks.